# Converting a float to its IEEE (32 bits) value

Tags: python, floating-point, ieee-754

I would like to write a script in python that takes a float value for example -37.32 and output its IEEE value (11000010000101010100011110101110). for the first bit if the number is negative than it is 1 else it's 0. for the exponent its the matter of dividing the number by 2 and getting the remainder if I am correct. as for the mantissa, I have no idea how to calculate it. returning a string would be the most reasonable way since it would be better for constructing each element of the IEEE.

can someone help me with the approach I will be taking? or show a script tackling this problem and explaining it to me?

Comment: _or show a script tackling this problem and explaining it to me?_ Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: yes I was able to make the exponent and the sign work but for the mantissa, I honestly have no idea how to get that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `struct` module can be used to convert a `float` to a sequence of bytes. Then it's just a matter of converting each byte to a binary string and joining them together.

```
>>> import struct
>>> ''.join('{:08b}'.format(b) for b in struct.pack('f', -37.32))
'10101110010001110001010111000010'
```

Comment: You probably want to use `">f"` instead of `"f"` for your format string, else on a little-endian machine the bits will be presented in a mixed-up order (bit 7 ... bit 0 bit 15 ... bit 8 ... bit 31 .. bit 24). The output you want here is presumably `11000010000101010100011110101110`.

Comment: @markdickinson I thought about that but I didn't know if the OP knew or cared about byte order so I just went with the default.

Comment: Right, byte order isn't really relevant here, but bit order is: if the OP is learning about the bit representation of a float, they will expect to see the sign bit at the beginning of the string, not somewhere in the middle. This solution also breaks the exponent field into two pieces. Note that if you pack with "f" and then unpack with "I" (with no byteorder specified in either case), and *then* convert to binary, you'll get the result the OP wants on either a bigendian _or_ a littleendian machine.